# Make vim run from cmd

Tags: vim, vi

Hello I'm running windows 7 and I have installed vim at : C:\Program Files\Vim\vim80 how can I run Vi at cmd console?And also how can I change the Esc key to F1 for example in Vi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run Vim from your console you have to include "C:\Program Files\Vim into your path directory with something like:

`set PATH="%PATH%;"C:Program Files\Vim""`

Now you should be able to open vim (and gvim) from cmd.

You can map any key, (say F2) to Esc with:

`:map <f2> <esc>
:imap <f2> <esc>`

However, to map F1 to Esc you first need to [remap the vim help](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Disable_F1_built-in_help_key)
to another key.

Comment: I tried pasting set PATH=%PATH%;"C:Program Files\Vim\vim80" in the cmd and then entered vi  or vim and it is still unrecognized

Comment: Sorry, I was missing two quotation marks. Now I edited my answer.

Comment: I have tried with the change ,again it is not recognized,after pasting and enterining I should start Vim by simply typing vim ,right?

Comment: Try `echo %PATH%` to verify that the vim directory has been included. If so, you should be able to open Vim from the console. Edit: I removed vim80 from the path.

Comment: it shows me C:Program Files\Vim;C:Program Files\Vim ,I try to start it like that in cmd C:\Users\MyName1>vim

Comment: Fixed I should have typed filename too